# What is the meaning of $\mathfrak{g}^*$?

Tags: notation, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have a simple notation question. When working with lie algebras, representations etc., I sometimes see $\mathfrak{g}^*$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is some lie algebra, but the star is never defined. What does it usually stand for?

Thank you!

Comment: You have seen the star already for vector spaces $V$, with the dual space $V^*$. In this sense recall that a Lie algebra is a vector space (with a Lie bracket). For cohomology, $H^n(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}^*)$ it also denotes the coadjoint module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the dual. That is, it's the space of all linear maps from $\mathfrak g$ into $k$, where $k$ is the field that you are working with.